# Get menu item to (un)check it

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to get a menu item to use the `.setChecked()`. But this should be in another function than the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. So I tried it with `findViewById()` but then I mentioned that this won't work^^ I googled but I can only find examples where they user it in the onOptionsItemSelected function and can use the `item` object. Is there any possibility to get the menu item like `findViewById`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get a menu item to use the .setChecked(). But this should be
>   in another function than the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

My first idea is to create "copy" of your `Menu` and then you have access to its child items.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   this.menuCopy = menu;
   new MenuInflater(<context>).inflate(layout, this.menuCopy);  
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(this.menuCopy);
}
```

And then you can use two methods:

- [`menu.getItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#getItem%28int%29) it returns menu item at the given index
- [`menu.findItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29) it returns menu item with a particular identifier

Comment: menuCopy.findItem(R.id.menu_id)

Comment: can I store the menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem); in a variable of type MenuItem?

Comment: @Phil for sure you can since it returns `MenuItem`

Comment: hm `MenuItem item = menuCopy.findItem(R.id.menuitem_autostart);` let the app crash totally :/

Comment: @Phil where you are calling that?

Comment: after class initialization I globally call `Menu menuCopy;` that I can use it everywhere, then in the onCreateOptionsMenu is this `menuCopy = menu;
     new MenuInflater(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.menu.menu_overview, this.menuCopy);    
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(this.menuCopy);` and in an extra public void I call this line which I already wrote, this function do I call in oncreate()

Comment: Ok already found the mistake... I can't call this before the menu is created^^ What a dump mistake of me, thanks for all your help guys